# Standard Data sources for CRM_ORDER_READ

Tags: sap-bw, sap-crm

Is there any standard data source available for Function Module `CRM_ORDER_READ`?

I want to pull CRM data to BW using standard data source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of CRM order related extractors (search RSA5), but you need to have clear insight what type of order information and schema you expect.

If you actually seek full control like you have with CRM_ORDER_READ, you best chance is to write your own generic extractor. [Follow this guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/10/19/generic-delta-how-to-extract-crm-order-user-status-changes/)